# changes on production server

Tags: php, symfony

I have my brand new symfony2 application up and running on production server. Unfortunatelly for me i need to do some changes in the files which are deployed, i NEED to edit files which are already there. I did it with nano, but unfortunatelly none of my applied changes are actually visible... What should I do to make those changes work for me? 
I tried

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

because it used to work for me on localhost when changes made to views couldnt do it, but right now it didn't really got me anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

There are two caches - production and development. `php app/console cache:clear` clears development cache  by default. Specify production cache to be cleared:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear `prod` cache as symfony2 "write down" two types of cache: `prod` and `dev`

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

With your command you are clearing only `dev` cache (default behaviour)

Comment: tried it, but i got an error saying "Unable to write in the "/path/user/public_html/forum/app/cache/prod"". i tried chmod -R 777 on it but got bunch of "operation not permitted" errors... (i cannot use sudo on this server unfortunatelly)

Comment: @Leo Read about setting up permissions - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup. You might need assistance from your hosting provider to set them up properly.

Comment: @Leo: maybe your webserver run with a different user, create files with 7x0 and you can't run chmod directly from your shell user. Are you logged as root?

Comment: @Leo: so maybe scenario I've write before is a realistic one. BTW set permissions to 777 isn't a good choice